# Smart card readers for MiFare Classic cards

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

While reading papers on how to attack MiFare Classic cards to figure out how secure is it, I have noticed many times that researchers talk about "genuine readers" and I couldn't understand very well what is meant by this term. Aren't all the readers deal in the same way with the cards? i.e. a reader at the place to be attacked can be replaced by any reader bought from the market.

Or is there some kind of key or per card reader configuration that gives every place that uses a card reader its unique identity that can't be replaced with any other new card reader bought from the market?

Answer (score 1):

Usually "genuine reader" (or rather "genuine reader system") refers to the reader (including its control software) as it is in use in a live application (access control gate, vending machine, etc.) Thus, this reader (again reader + control software) knows how to access the cards (including the knowledge of the keys necessary to access any protect information on the card).

This term is used to differentiate from a reader that can (technically) communicate with the same card technology but does not (necessarily) have information on how to access the card (or at least does not have knowledge of any necessary secret keys).

For instance with MIFARE Classic, an attacker can compute the keys from any genuine card using any suitable (in terms of the key breaking attack) reader, even if the reader does not (yet) have knowledge about the actual keys of the card. The only requirement is to have a genuien card (i.e. a card that works in the system under attack).

Comment: so the term "geniune reader" is used to refer to a reader that has additional control software (on specialized board or on a regular computer if the reader is USB connected) used to deal with extra layers of encryption of the data on the card, which are layers beyond the default encryption layer offered by MiFare chip, and this extra layers are the ones that are customed to the system under attack?

Comment: I would not call it an extra layer as this "genuine" already includes MIFARE keys. But other than that: yes.

Comment: what do you mean by MiFare keys, is it possible to set custom key for the reader crypto1 encryption to make it different from any other reader in the market? let me put it in another way, if the data on the card are plain and only depends on MiFare encryption and i got a genuine card and a new reader from the market, i can perform the attack with this setting?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you start with looking into how MIFARE Classic works (Google will give you a good start ;-) before we continue any discussion. From the above comment I'm not sure that you understood how MIFARE works.